# He believes that the world is round OR He believes the world is round

Tags: conjunctions, optional-that

Which of the following sentences look better in formal writing:

"He believes that the world is round" OR "He believes the world is round"

Comment: You can use either; they're both formally correct. But which one looks better is a matter of opinion I'm afraid. Personally I'd try to avoid sentences with too many "that"s in (e.g., "I think that that is a good question"), otherwise it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but omitting "that" is more common in informal and spoken English. For formal writing, it is best to include "that".

Comment: @JavaLatte That would make a good answer if you could back it up with some authoritative sources. Until then, I stand by my statement (that) it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @MrLister - I think it may be context-dependent, too; that is, I might be inclined to include or omit the "that" depending on the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> He believes **that** the world is round
>   He believes the world is round

The meanings are equivalent, the "***that***" is assumed but not used in the second sentence.  This often happens in speech and writing, consider

> He believes *(that)*...
>   He thinks *(that)*...
>   He knows *(that)*...